# Cross-Stack Lambda and API Gateway Permissions with AWS-CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have two code bases. One defines a service (Service A) that includes an AWS lambda which queries a dynamoDB table.

Another, defines an aggregating API Gateway which needs to call multiple service lambdas.

The API Gateway imports the lambda defined in service A using a cross stack reference and creates a Lambda integration for it:

```js
    const queryTrackFunction = lambda.Function.import(this, 'TrackQueryServiceQueryTrackFunction', {
      functionArn: cdk.Fn.importValue('TrackQueryServiceStack:QueryTrackFunctionArn')
    })

    const customerApi = new api.RestApi(this, 'CustomerAPI')
    
    const tracks = customerApi.root.addResource('tracks')
    tracks.addMethod('GET', new api.LambdaIntegration(queryTrackFunction))
```

When the API is invoked it fails, presumably because the apigateway service has not been given invoke permissions.

In the aws-cdk project for Service A I add the following:

```js
queryTracksFunction.grantInvoke(new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com'))
```

When I attempt to deploy the service I get this error:

> Error: Cannot use tokens in construct ID: Invoke{"Service":["${Token[TOKEN.139]}"]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. As a workaround, in your Service A, you can do:

```ts
queryTracksFunction.addPermission('APIGateway', {
  principal: new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com')
});
```

Comment: Would this expose your lambda to execution via apigateway from a different AWS account?

Comment: does this work? cdk doesn't output any new resources when i add this for an imported function (from another stack), guess it's a cdk bug..